# "Divide by zeror error has encountred", there are null values in T0 and T3 doctotal and it cant excecute null values

Tags: sql, null, ssms, isnull, sapb1

I am getting a divide by zero error in my SQL Query, does anyone know why this is happening?

```
           SELECT 
           T4.CardCode as 'Customer Code', 
           T4.CardName as 'Customer Name', 
           T0.DocEntry as 'Invoice No',
            ISNULL(T0.DocTotal, 0 ) as 'Invoice Amount', 
            ISNULL(T3.DocTotal, 0 ) as 'Credit Note', 
            ISNULL((T3.DocTotal/T0.DocTotal), 0)*100 as 'Credit Note%', 
            ISNULL((T0.DocTotal-T3.DocTotal), 0) as 'Recovered'
            ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(T3.DocTotal, 0 ) = 0 AND  ISNULL((T0.DocTotal), 0) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE
             ((ISNULL((T0.DocTotal -T3.DocTotal), 0))/SUM((ISNULL(T0.DocTotal, 0))-(ISNULL(T3.DocTotal, 0)))*100) end  as 'Sales%'

             FROM OINV T0
             INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
             LEFT OUTER JOIN RIN1 T2 ON T1.DocEntry = T2.BaseEntry
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ORIN T3 ON T2.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OCRD T4 ON T0.CardCode = T4.CardCode

             Group by T4.CardCode, T4.CardName,  T0.DocEntry, T0.DocTotal, T3.DocTotal
             Order by T4.CardCode, T0.DocEntry
```

Comment: Your overuse of parentheses makes it all very difficult to read. Presumably, the error comes from the Sales% calculation. So what do you want to happen when a divide by zero occurs (which probably would be a divide by null without the `isnull`)? Do you want to divide by 1 instead? Or do you want to return `null`? Both these options are simple, practically self-evident. So what do you want to happen?

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend to give more descriptive table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The only division I see is:

```
. . . / SUM((ISNULL(T0.DocTotal, 0))-(ISNULL(T3.DocTotal, 0))) * 100
```

Your logic should be:

```
100.0 * . . . / NULLIF(SUM(T0.DocTotal) - COALESCE(T3.DocTotal, 0), 0)
```

That is, the denominator is replaced by `NULL` if the expression is `0`.  That prevents the divide-by-zero.

I moved the `100.0 *` just because I don't like to have to figure out if the numerator is being multiplied or the denominator.

Comment: The sum of Sales % should become **100** in total. Now its coming 75....... I am editing the SUM of Sales% in the report builder, because i need to calculate Sum of everything. This is a customer wise invoice detail report

Comment: @RafeyDRappu . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  I would suggest you ask a *new* question.  Simplify the data and the query, to the extent that you can.  Provide sample data and desired results and be clear about what you need.